# jQuery UI tabs example - opening new tab = adding unique script to each tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

This is jQuery tabs script: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#manipulation

```
        var $tabs = $( "#tabs").tabs({
            tabTemplate: "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close'>Remove Tab</span></li>",
            add: function( event, ui ) {
                var tab_content = $tab_content_input.val() || "Tab " + tab_counter + " content.";
                $( ui.panel ).append( "<p>" + tab_content + "</p>" );
            }
        });

// rest of script
```

So, what's I need? I need to script will be setting (with other content) on line var tab_content = . Normally (in script with static tabs) my own script is loading on the bottom of page (i was create a few instance of the same script like (founction(script1), founciton(script2) and 2 divs with id script1 and script2), after all HTML code, but in this case I don't know how to do this. I need to script be unique for each tabs.

Comment: can you clarify your question (if there is one)?

Comment: I need to my (not ui tabs) script/function will be loaded seperatly in the bottom of page when new tab is created or changed. I tried to put script/founciton into  "var tab_content =" but it doesn't works. 

In version without ui tabs (without possibility to add a new tab or remove, static tabs) it looks sth like that: <div id="script1"></div> <div id="script2"></div> <script> founction(script1) function(script2)</script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that the underlying HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a name="my_id" href="/watman">Hey</a></li>
    <li><a name="test_it" href="/brown-chicken-brown-cow">Hey2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here's what I used in such situation. In **global script** I define variables

```
var _SCRIPT = {};
var _CURRENT_TAB = '#ui-tabs-1';
var _CURRENT_TAB_NAME = 'my_id';
```

Now for each tab I load a script in the head of the **main** view (after the global script). The scripts I'm loading look like this:

```
_SCRIPT['my_id'] = {
  tab: null,
  init: function() {
    this.tab = _CURRENT_TAB;
    // initialize script
  },
  // some other fields
}
```

where `my_id` is the name that is going to be associated with the tab I'm going to load. Next I generate tabs with my main JavaScript like this:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
  // some other options
  ajaxOptions: {
    cache: false,
    complete: function() {
      _SCRIPT[_CURRENT_TAB_NAME].init();
    },
  },
  select: function(event, ui) {
    _CURRENT_TAB = $(ui.tab).attr('href');
    _CURRENT_TAB_NAME = $(ui.tab).attr('name');
  },
  cache: true,
});
```

Now every html that goes inside a tab, say `my_id` can be accessed via jQuery like this (code from function `_SCRIPT['my_id'].init` or any other function inside `_SCRIPT['my_id']`):

```
console.log( $('a', this.tab) );
```

Note that this will return elements only inside `my_id` tab.

Side note 1: I do not recommend inserting script tags via ajax. Hard to debug and you can easily loose control over ''namespaces''. Also you will have problems whenever you reload the tab.

Side note 2: be careful about defining `id` attribute on elements in tabs. Keep in mind that they need to be unique across the HTML document.

Comment: ajaxOptions doesn't work for me :( also _SCRIPT. I tried also to alert() append, or text something on my website in _SCRIPT, or directly into ajaxOptions() in complete section but it doesn't works.

Comment: Try putting those 3 variables `_SCRIPT`, `_CURRENT_TAB` and `_CURRENT_TAB_NAME` at the top of your HTML (before any script tag) in a script tag. And what do you mean `ajaxOptions` does not work? Any errors?

Comment: Ok, it works, but i have to resign for _SCRIPT. I place it to add: :) Can you tell me how to get an current tab title? :) Tab title is in the href. I try `$(ui.tab).attr('href').val()` but it doesn't works for me.

Comment: Just `$(ui.tab).attr('href')`.

Comment: It shows only title like #tabs-1, #tabs-2. I want to get an title of current tab.

Comment: What do you understand by title? You mean the inner text in a tab element? `$(ui.tab)` gives you entire `a` element. You can access the inner text like you access any other inner text via jQuery: `$(ui.tab).text()` for example. I advice adding additional property to `a` definition though, for example `<a data-title="my_title" ... >...</a>` and use `$(ui.tab).attr('data-title');`.